# Errors trying to fetch users from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase

I am trying to fetch users form my Firebase database, display their names on the UITableView and be able to search through them. For some reason, I am seeing two errors on this function to fetch users.

1. ERROR: Value of type 'User' has no member 'append' at the line 'self.users.append(user)'
2. ERROR: No 'dispatch_get_main_queue' candidates produce the expected contextual result type '(DispatchQueue, () -> Void)' at the line 'dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)'

If you know any way to fix this please let me know. I've been stuck on this for a while now and can't seem to get the users to display. Thanks.

```
    func fetchUser() {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        
        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let user = User()
            
            //will crash if your class properties don't exactly match up with firebase dictionary keys
            user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary)
            self.users.append(user)
            
            
            //this will crash because of background thread, so use dispatch async to fix
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print(user.name!, user.email!)
```

Comment: I commented on this exact problem on your question from yesterday already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62616575/error-fetching-users-from-firebase-in-swift#comment110734138_62616575. In the future if a comment isn't clear, respond to it instead of reposting the same problem.

Comment: Sorry about that, and thank you for responding yesterday. That post had been closed because it wasn't formatted correctly and I did not see your response. My bad, new here. Thanks again for answering it

Answer (score 1):

Second error is because that's not a proper syntax for running something on main thread. Should be

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

As for the first error, I can only speculate (since you didn't provide how `self.users` is defined. But I suspect you defined it as `var users: User`, instead of array. So make sure you have:

```
var users: [User]
```

or with initialization:

```
var users = [User]()
```